# Gaussian mixture vs. Gaussian process

Tags: regression, gaussian-process, gaussian-mixture-distribution

As far as I know, both **Gaussian mixtures** as well as **Gaussian processes** can be used for regression. My question is: what is better and why?

The answers might contain theoretic insights, practical experience or reference to further resources.

---

EDIT

I would like to know which one is better for approximation of nonlinear regression problems
$$Y_i=g(x_i)+V_i$$
where $V_i\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ for all considered $i$. The function $g(\cdot)$ is assumed to be continuous. For the simplicity sake, we can admit that $x_i\in\mathbb{R}$. The criterion is the one-leave out mean square error.

The second criterion, perhaps more important. Since I assume that both (GM and GP) have the universal approaximation property, I would be curious which one is less complex (in terms of time and/or memory) in order to obtain given level of error.

Finally, I assume that the new data points $(x_i,y_i)$ can be generated on demand with a constant computational compexity.

Comment: "Better" for what purpose and context? You might as well ask "which is better--digging with a spade or digging with a fork--and why?"  Please, then, edit this question to provide this information that is essential for getting objective, useful answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer your last question, Gaussian process is a discriminative model as opposed to generative.  Therefore, you will not be able to model $p(x, y)$ using Gaussian process.  Gaussian process models $p(y | x)$ instead.  To generate samples $(x_i, y_i)$ you need to work with a generative model such as Gaussian mixture model.